# Need feature name: ethernet switch recognizes manual cable disconnect and shuts down the port

Tags: security, switch, ethernet, intrusion-detection

Once in a hospital's radiology department, we had this nifty security feature -- I just cannot remember the proper name to succeed at various search engines:

If a host's ethernet cable was disconnected, the uplink switch recognized this and as result declared the corresponding port as switched off, no matter if the cable was reconnected immediately. Manual interaction was required to get the link working again.

Seemed to be a useful intrusion countermeasure to prevent people from replacing hosts. Is this a standard feature I just miss to find?

Comment: Not exactly, what you ask, but check IEEE 802.1X

Comment: Thanks for replying! But indeed, it was not 802.1X since immediately reconnecting an authorized host did not make the system work again without manual interaction. Something I had to find out. It's never funny to have a busy sysop getting after you. ;-)

Comment: That's not a standard feature - I don't know any switch implementing that. Depending on your security requirements, you should look into 802.1X or - much better - MACsec.